# CSS margin change on div:hover in IE8 and 9 not working correctly with facebook like box, jumps sporadically

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, facebook-javascript-sdk, xfbml, css-animations

We have a slide out CSS box that we use on our website, and when we inserted the facebook like box into the div container that slides, it acts very sporadic in IE8.

The CSS code used is:

```
#sliding_box {
                position:absolute;
                width:425px;
                height:500px;
                background: url(./images/layout/facebook.png);

                top:200px;
                left:0px;               
                -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
                -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
                transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;                 

                margin-left: -387px;      


            }                       

            #sliding_box:hover{

                margin-left: 0px;
            }
```

and the HTML is:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=2422861308";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
        <div id="sliding_box">
            <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/scopestop" data-

width="387" data-height="500" data-show-faces="true" data-border-color="gray" data-

stream="true" data-header="true"></div>
        </div>
```

It seems that once the like box loads, it does not consider hovering over the like box to be hovering over the div container. Before the like box loads and it only shows white space, it does not act incorrectly.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m4xg8/3/

The fiddle is now working properly.

I tried to use the absolute positioning in place of the margin-left to make the box slide, but I run into the same problem in internet explorer (8 and 9).

Unfortunately changing the invalid characters on the website as suggested did not fix the problem either.

I have asked my web devlopment teacher and PHP instructor for help, but they did not have any idea. Anyone out there familiar with the Facebook like box and using it with move on hover CSS containers?

Comment: Please always post a demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) in which you reproduce the issue. It'd help you get answers much faster, and makes the question clearer.

Comment: I've tried a number of modifications to the CSS, and nothing seems to work. does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some invalid characters in your webpage:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I fixed the characters, and unfortunately it did not help. Thanks for pointing that out.